# Replacing an anchor with link & truncated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, anchor

I have a javascript function that I use to detect and replace links with an anchor (html). However, the problem is that some people paste in massive links that cause page elements to overlow, which breaks the page (typically).

Does anyone know a simple way to combine the following two functions into one that provides an anchor tag with a truncated version of the link inside it?

IE converting

```
http://Superlonglink
```

Into

```
<a href="http://Superlonglink">http://Super...</a>
```

Using a combination of the following functions:

**Function to replace links with anchors:**

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
}
```

**Function to truncate a string:**

```
String.prototype.trunc = function(n){
      return this.substr(0,n-1)+(this.length>n?'':'');
};
```

I've been playing around with this for a while, however I'm finding my understanding of regex with javascript is a bit limited

Comment: Instead of truncating the string using JavaScript you might try to use CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;` I don't know if that'll work in your case, but anyway. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text, maxlen) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp, function( link ) {
        return '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' +
            (link.length > maxlen ? link.substring( 0, maxlen ) + "..." : link) + '</a>'
    });
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/84Le9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use a function inside the replace so you can manipulate it.

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,
        function (href) {
            var partial = href.length<10 ? href : href.substring(0,10) + "...";
            return "<a href='" + href + "' target='_blank'>"+ partial + "</a>"});
}



replaceURLWithHTMLLinks("http://www.example.com/IAMAVERYLONGLINKWITHMORESTUFF");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu94C/)